# CallbackDataProvider's fetchCallback is not callbacked, so the grid is empty

Tags: java, spring, grid, vaadin

I am trying to use the "Grid" vaadin component to simply display a list of POJO. To populate the POJO list I use the DataProvider.fromCallbacks and set a Spring service to it. The grid is correctly displayed but the content is empty. When I run the app in debug mode I can see that the callback method is never called, that's why the grid is empty.

It's a basic use of grid so i really don't understand why the callback isn't used.

Here is my layout :

```
@SpringComponent
@Route("")
@PWA(name = "Callcenter dashboard", shortName = "callcenter")
public class CallcenterConfigurationView extends VerticalLayout {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurationController configurationControler;

    private Grid<CallCenterModel> grid;

    public CallcenterConfigurationView() {
        this.grid =   new Grid<CallCenterModel>();

        grid.addColumn(CallCenterModel::getDescription).setHeader("Description");

        add(grid);

        setSizeFull();

    }


    @PostConstruct
    public void initDataProvider() {

        CallbackDataProvider<CallCenterModel, Void> dataProvider =     DataProvider.fromCallbacks(
                query -> configurationControler.findAllcenters().stream(), 
                query -> configurationControler.countAllcallcenters()
                );
        grid.setDataProvider(dataProvider);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot try out your code as-is since I lack the implementations of `ConfigurationController` and `CallCenterModel`. When I fill in the blanks based on my own assumptions, I end up with something where the callback is indeed called. That causes another error, but that's a different story.

Some wild guesses for why the query method won't be called in your case:

- Maybe the count callback returns 0? In that case, there's no need to fetch any items.
- Maybe there's something that prevents `initDataProvider` from being run at all so that the grid doesn't use your data provider?
- Maybe there's something else that assigns a different data provider to the grid after your data provider has been assigned?

Testing whether any of those things happen should be quite straightforward either by setting some breakpoints or by adding some logging.

Everything works works for me if I slightly adapt your code to abstract away the `ConfigurationController` part so that I don't need a database to run the example. (I've also done a couple of other small tweaks just to make the example a couple of lines shorter)

```
@SpringComponent
@Route("dashboard")
public class CallcenterConfigurationView extends VerticalLayout {
    // My approximation of the relevant parts of CallCenterModel
    public static class CallCenterModel {
        private String description;

        public CallCenterModel(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }
    }

    // A fake "database" containing 100 instances 
    private static List<CallCenterModel> callCenterModels = IntStream.range(0, 100)
            .mapToObj(index -> new CallCenterModel("Call center " + index))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    private Grid<CallCenterModel> grid = new Grid<>();

    public CallcenterConfigurationView() {
        grid.addColumn(CallCenterModel::getDescription).setHeader("Description");

        add(grid);

        setSizeFull();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initDataProvider() {
        CallbackDataProvider<CallCenterModel, Void> dataProvider = DataProvider.fromCallbacks(
            query -> callCenterModels
                     .subList(query.getOffset(), query.getOffset() + query.getLimit())
                     .stream(),
            query -> callCenterModels.size());
        grid.setDataProvider(dataProvider);
    }
}
```

Comment: The configuration controller simply fetch data from business service, which fetch thoses from repository (basic entity to DTO to Model mapping). This does return datas into the controler.

The callcenter model is a simple Pojo which various strings fields, nothing really unusual.

When I put a log or a breakpoint into the count callback method I see that it isn't called at all.

I've put a sysout into "initDataProvider" and the log is printed, so the method is run.

It is possible that another data provider  is set to the grid, but I don't how to check that.

Comment: You could try setting a breakpoint in `Grid.setDataProvider`.

Comment: Another theoretical possibility is that `initDataProvider` is for some weird reason run only after the basic information about the grid has already been sent to the client. If this is the case, then the data should appear automatically once Vaadin does a roundtrip for some other reason, e.g. if you also add a dummy button with a click listener and click that button. That's of course not a real solution, but it would help determine whether this is the case.

Comment: Thank You Leif, I've put a breakpoint ont the "setDataProvider" method, but it is only called once at the startup. I think I should try to populate the grid another way, I don't really know what is the best practice

Comment: I've tried to use "setItems", but it's still doesn't display anything. So know i'm wondering if the CallcenterModel isn't displayable. Is there any condition to display an item ?

Comment: Without knowing all the details that are not apparent from your example and without knowing exactly what you've already verified, my strongest suspicion would be that `countAllcallcenters` for some reason `0`. I've also added a working adaption of your original example code to my answer.

Comment: Nevermind, I endup that my spring configuration wasn't properly made. It was a former Spring MVC Rest + AngularJS project that I am migrating, and I was a little confused by all the spring boot configuration. Thank you for the time you spend on my problem !